# Free, downloadable Helvetica small caps? Well, then, how about Arial or even Tahoma?

Tags: font-recommendation, sans-serif

I'm looking for Arial non-fake small-caps. Free, downloadable, and TrueType or OpenType.

A free Helvetica would be great but I don't know that Mono ever made small caps for this typeface. I will also settle for Tahoma smalls. Or please suggest a better Helvetica seem-alike.

Is there a free source for any of these fonts?

Comment: Free, probably not...

Comment: Especially not for fonts that aren't free in the first place...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly certain nobody has ever drawn small caps for any flavor of Helvetica, nor for Arial. I  don't know offhand of *any* grotesk that's free and contains small caps. Given how solid they are, I can see small caps being quite a challenge, so perhaps it's not entirely surprising. Relatively few sans faces, comparatively, seem to have had SC drawn at any point, especially the grotesks. Even the exquisitely versatile Myriad Pro has no small caps -- an amazing omission for a modern digital face, particularly from Adobe.

If all you need is a sans with true small caps, and you don't want to pay for one, several OpenType sans faces with small caps (Calibri is one) ship free with MS Office, Vista, and Win7. Keep in mind that your application must be OpenType-aware in order to access them, however.

Comment: Note that the basic idea behind a small-caps font for a typeface set is that the small caps have the same visual impact and weight (or as near as possible) as the regular lower-case text when set. If one has access to a full enough set of weight options for a particular typeface family, one might be able to simulate small caps effectively.

Comment: Half a year ago Arial got true small caps :)

Answer (score 6):

[TeX Gyre Heros](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/heros) (based on Nimbus Sans L, which in its self is a URW's Helvetica), has small caps and is freely available.

Comment: \usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros} 

Or see https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/texgyreheros/

Answer (score 4):

Since 2014 Arial has full set of small caps. You can download it with Windows 10 Tech Preview ISO → http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-iso

[image]