# Arial Small Caps -- how to use them?

Tags: fonts, typography, software-recommendation, typesetting, resource-recommendations

According to [this answer to another question about small caps](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/44625/129354) by [@yakunins](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/5791/yakunins), Arial got small caps around 2014:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/otPZ2.png]
>
> (image provided by [@yakunins](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/5791/yakunins))

So, how do you use them? Is this Arial or Arial Nova?  What application(s) allow you to access these features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the default Arial packaged with Windows 10 comes with true small caps included, and below is a screenshot of InDesign's glyphs panel — basically a list of every character in a font.

If you get to use InDesign, there is literally a 'Small Caps' button, that you click and the app renders any selected text in small caps:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/formatting-characters.html

I don't use any other apps, but they all probably use small caps, one way or another, even [Word does](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-capitalization-or-case-of-text-1d86cf80-fbef-4380-8d6f-59a6b77db749).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my copy of Word doesn't. Microsoft Word 2016 has "OpenType" choices in the Font dialog box, but when you choose "small caps" it uses simulated small caps, not OpenType small caps. :-(

Comment: You're probably right, Word is not quite the tool for this. That's why I mentioned InDesign first, that's what I use.

Answer (score 5):

The actual methods to use small caps will depend on the software you are using. Here's how to use it in Inkscape for example:

1. Using the Type Tool, type some text, highlight it, make sure the font is Arial.
2. Open the Text and Font dialog <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Click on the Features tab, click on Capitals, choose "Small". Hit Apply.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Any application that supports opentype features. Most graphic design applications, web browsers and word processors allow you to set the style to small caps.

Comment: Microsoft Word 2016 is OpenType aware, but when you choose "small caps" it uses simulated small caps, not OpenType small caps. :-(

Comment: Yes @whiskeychief if you check effects category after all that was the effect is supposed to do. But if you go to advanced section then you can chose opentype options. Anyway, i still havent found a single good reason to use Word for anything other than some really obscure programming related stuff. Mainly because it makes so many simple tasks near impossible. Also if you meant to ask how to do this in word why didnt you ask about word?